# Computer stuck on either black screen with blue flashing light or stuck on "Check Cable Signal

Tags: windows-10, display

So what caused the problem was the processor I put in. My brother was previously using it and it worked properly on his, but when I try using it, it doesn't work, When I put in the previous processor it all works but my old processor is causing lag on my computer. I switch the newer one between my computer and my brothers and it works on his but not on mine.
I also have a GTX 1060.
970 Gaming Motherboard
And 8 GB of ram.
The monitor is a Samsung SyncMaster 205BW.

Comment: We could use a little more information to effectively help you. When you say 'previous processor' do you mean you switched out the CPU (intel or AMD) and now things don't work correctly? We also need to know the full model of that motherboard. I can't really figure out 970 gaming motherboard. Brand, socket type, full name?(i.e. Gigabyte Z-970 LGA 1151)

Comment: I had an AMD 4430 I believe then I upgraded to an AMD FX 8350. The motherboard is MSI 970 Gaming ( what it says on the box), not sure the socket type tho.

Comment: I googled AMD 4430 and got a bunch of intel Core i5 4430 CPUs. If you were trying to put an AMD chip in an intel board, they are not compatible and will not work. You're lucky you didn't bend any of the pins underneath the CPU!

Comment: Its an AMD motherboard and an AMD CPU, I had an AMD before and it worked fine, but now with the new one its as if the screen can't be detected, I checked and rechecked all the cords, I checked the CPU to see if any of the little metal things were broke(none were), I checked to see if anything was broke and nothing was, I checked cords and different types, such as VGA, DVI-D, and HDMI. I don't know what the problem would be

Comment: It may be an incompatible socket type. Can you clarify which CPU you *had* and which CPU you are trying to put in now?

Comment: O had an AMD 4400 before, now I'm.trying a 8350

Comment: Like I had said tho, my brother and I have almost the exact same build, the only difference is the CPU and Graphic card

Comment: The CPU socket for AMD FX-4400 is AM2. The CPU socket for an AMD FX-8350 is AM3+. That is why it is incompatible. You would have to buy a new motherboard with an AM3+ socket to use the 8350.

Comment: Then how did it work on my brothers computer? We have the exact same motherboard

Comment: If you have some time, go to https://www.piriform.com/speccy and download the application on both you and your brothers machines, after it installs it will list the components you have in your machine. From there, make sure that the Motherboard listing is exactly the same, otherwise they most likely are not.

Comment: I can't install it on my computer because I can't see the screen, I tried putting the other CPU in and same thing, no response to the screen even tho it worked before putting in the new CPU

Comment: Well, sounds like it may have been bricked during the times you were trying to swap out CPU's.